# Why does Fermi level restrict conduction?

Tags: electromagnetism, wavefunction, charge

Newbie question: In proximity to a positive charge, why does an electron need any charge other than its own fundamental negative nature in order to conduct?

Comment: Could you provide more precision about the situation that you are asking about?

Comment: Maybe! An electron, by definition, has a negative charge. In the case of an electron below the Fermi level, that negative charge has little power. If it contacts a positively charged object, say, a lone hydrogen nucleus, would it or would it not conduct in the sense of taking part in the proton’s nonequilibrium valence shell? Does this make sense?